# Why do we have to make a copy of the state in Flutter Riverpod State Notifier

Tags: flutter, riverpod

My Flutter Riverpod State Notifier maintains an array of more than 10000 large objects. One of the properties of the object is a boolean flag `isFavorite`. The flag toggles value when the user clicks a button.

Now, should I necessarily make a clone of the entire object array in order to trigger a state change notification? This seems to be wasteful of resources when only a single bit has changed. Is there a more efficient way to just change the flag in one object and force Riverpod to take notice?

Is there a Riverpod-equivalent of `setState()` in Stateful Widgets ?

Comment: Take a look at the reasoning for the immutable state: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/why_immutability.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a Riverpod-equivalent of `setState()` in `StatefulWidget`s ?

You can use [`useState`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useState.html) from [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) package. The Riverpod documentation suggests to [AVOID using providers for local widget state](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/do_dont#avoid-using-providers-for-local-widget-state), and mentioned [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) as one solution to be considered.

You can then replace [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package with [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod), and use the hooks inside `HookConsumerWidget` which allows you to use both hooks and Riverpod.

More about Riverpod+hooks: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_hooks

Answer (score 0):

You can override `updateShouldNotify` in your `Notifier` subclass to use equality rather than identity, and ensure that your state has a valid equality (overridden `==` and `hashCode`).  Then, you will never need to copy your state, just be sure to call `ref.notifyListeners` for any possible mutations.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I have a follow up question: 
What if I maintain my data entirely outside of the Notifier class? I can have a simple Notifier with only a boolean state. Whenever a Consumer modifies part of the data, this boolean flag will be flipped, triggering a notification.
In this case, I will be completely responsible for data integrity, concurrency etc. Does your solution mitigate some of these problems?